# Pause game when home button is pressed for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

I wish to pause a game when the user presses the home button, however I fail to do so. Here's what I did.

1. I declare a NSInteger variable in appdelegate called gamestate and define two constant (kGameStateRunning and kGameStatePaused) to update the variable.
2. When viewdidload for my mainGameViewController, i set gamestate = kGameStateRunning
3. So what I want to do here is when a user presses home button, a pauseView is added to current mainGameViewController just like what a user will see when he presses a pause button during game play which I created.

I implement it in the appdelegate function and uses it to call a pauseGame method in my viewController. The NSLog shows that home button is pressed but it does not seem to add the pause view that i created programmatically to it. Is it because it doesn't understand [self.view addSubView:pauseView] if I were to call this in appDelegate. Thank you for your help. Here's the code.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (gameState == kGameStateRunning) {
        [self.viewController pauseGame];
        NSLog(@"home button pressed");
    }
    else if (gameState == kGameStatePaused) {
        NSLog(@"not running");

-(void)pauseGame{
//pause all functions
NSLog(@"pause");
[gameTimer invalidate];
[hHpointer.packageSpawningTime invalidate];

for (Package *package in hHpointer.packageArray) {
    [package.timeSinceSpawn invalidate];
}

//create the view
pauseView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[pauseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
pauseView.alpha = 0.5;
[self.view addSubview:pauseView];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling this from the app delegate you have a pointer to a window, not a view.

As such, you should call: `[self.window addSubview:pauseView];`

When the app starts over make sure to implement the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:` method.

And remove the view calling `[pauseView removeFromSuperview]`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: suppose my pauseView is created in a landscape mode, pauseView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320), it does not seem to cover the window properly. How do I tilt my window orientation?